# Overriding Access-Control-Allow-Origin restriction in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cross-browser

I make AJAX calls to URIs which belong to a different domain. Normally in IE I am able to do this via jQuery's CORS support. But this fails in Google Chrome irrespective where CORS support is set or not.

Now I get an error saying something like:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Origin `http://localhost:8000` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is there a setting in Google Chrome which disables the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* restriction?

Comment: Do you have control over the remote web resource? You could add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a command-line switch which does the trick: `--disable-web-security`

Just call it like follows:

```
$ chromium-browser --disable-web-security http://localhost:8000/pages/index.html
```

Make sure the Chrome browser is fully closed, otherwise it will only launch a new instance and the applied option will not work.

Comment: The `--disable-web-security` option doesn't seam to work on Google Chrome, only on Chromium though.

Comment: Tested today in Chrome, works fine.

Comment: `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security` executed in the mac terminal works fine for me. It has to be done when Chrome is not running though.

Comment: Tested on 14-12-2012 on Chrome. Works fine but shows a message saying "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer"

Comment: "Make sure the Chrome browser is fully closed" -- This was key for me.  You should open task manager and make sure all the chrome.exe processes are gone.

Comment: If you are using Mac try this one "open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security" Without the quote